How to access bill city, bill state, bill zip and bill country from sales order user event script?
How to access bill city, state, zip, country from billing address of sale order using user event script?
function afterSubmit(context) {
if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE && context.type !== context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
return;
}
var salesOrder = context.newRecord;
var city = salesOrder.getValue({ fieldId: 'billcity' });
var state = salesOrder.getValue({ fieldId: 'billstate' });
var zip = salesOrder.getValue({ fieldId: 'billzip' });
var country = salesOrder.getValue({ fieldId: 'billcountry' });
log.debug('Sales Order Address', 'City: ' + city + ', State: ' + state + ', Zip: ' + zip + ', Country: ' + country);
}
Getting log as:
City:undefined, State:undefined, Zip:undefined, Country:undefined

You need to load the billingaddress subrecord, then access the fields from there.
var billAddrSubRec = salesOrder.getSubrecord({
    fieldId: 'billingaddress'
});
var city = billAddrSubRec.getValue({
    fieldId: 'city'
});

And so on.  You can find the available fields for the sales order record at https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2023_1/script/record/salesorder.html and the fields for the address subrecord at https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2023_1/script/record/address.html
